# Sending daily SMS a specific time

Tags: php, sql, sms

I am working on a site that allows users to enter their phone number and carrier, and choose a time to receive a daily alert via SMS.

I am inserting information (phone number, carrier, and time) into an SQL database, then using php's `mail()` function to send SMS texts to their phone by email (i.e. if a Verizon user's number is `123456789`, I would send an SMS by emailing to `123456789@vtext.com`).

I cannot figure out how to send the SMS every day repeatedly, as well as how to send it at the specific time the user selects. What approach could I take to do this?

Comment: cron job, to check the db for txts that should be sent, run once per minute.

Comment: Begging for quick replies because you're on a deadline isn't really a good idea. `:)` Just ask your question, most of the answers will come in the first hour or so in most cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use some scheduler application like **"[cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)"** in Unix machines or **"[Scheduled Tasks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569)"** in Windows machines. Use one of those apps to schedule a job for execute a php file at the time and day pattern you want.

Comment: I've been researching using "cron" to have a php file run every minute and check for jobs.  Basically I'll have a database for users and each user can choose a time to receive a message. so say for example user1 wants to receive it at 7:00am and user2 wants to receive it at 12:30am.  If I have cron run a php script every 5 minutes, then how can i make the php script only send messages to users (if any) who have selected that current time?

Comment: use the logic inside the php file to get current time and then get relevant users for that time. then send message only to those users.

Answer (score -1):

You either have to have an SMS Gateway (hardware) or use some other service to do so.

For example:
http://www.sms4pc.com/api-start?gclid=CKei9Yr_7qwCFRLatgodGyNJKQ

Comment: That's not really what the question is, it's really about how to setup a scheduled task to run it at a specific time.

Comment: Plus you can SMS without a gateway, though it is much trickier (you have to know the carrier, and the e-mail address the carrier exposes to send e-mail-to-SMS).

Comment: Yeah, but even then, the messages tend to be formatted differently (extra message at the beginning or end).